# Matlab file name concatenation

Tags: matlab, directory, concatenation

```
%% File Names reading and label generation 

dataFolder= 'allcontent';
fileNames = dir([dataFolder 'c*.*']);

lbl = sscanf(cat(1,'fileNames.name'),'co2%c%d.rd.%d');
status = lbl(1:3:end);
id = lbl(2:3:end);
ids = unique(id);
trial = lbl(3:3:end);
```

I want to concatenate the names of all the files in the folder titled all content , at the moment, matlab doesn't understand what allcontent is. Can someone help me get the contents of the folder ' all content'  which are of the form  'c*.*' and then concatenate them?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `fullfile` to concatenate paths in Matlab, i.e.

```
fileNames = dir(fullfile(dataFolder, 'c*.*'));
```

Also, I don't think `fileNames.name` should be in quotes. As @Wolfie mentioned, you can concatenate the filenames into a cell array using `{fileNames.name}`

```
filenames_array = {fileNames.name}
```

Then you can iterate over `filenames_array` using `for` or `cellfun`

Comment: From memory (untested) you will need to group `fileNames.name` using curly braces to make it a single cell array, like `{fileNames.name}`

Comment: @Wolfie You're right. Turning into a cell array also means you can use `for` or `celllfun` to iterate over the filenames.